# SQL execute return of select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have select

```
select 'alter table '+so.name+
' drop '+sdc.name+' go sp_bindefault ''abc'' ,'''+so.name+'.'+sc.name+''''
from sys.objects as so
       join sys.columns as sc on so.object_id=sc.object_id
       join sys.default_constraints as sdc on sc.object_id=sdc.parent_object_id
                                                      and sc.column_id=sdc.parent_column_id
where so.type='U'
        and so.name like 'z%'
        and sdc.definition='(getdate())'
```

Im droping getdate defaults and want bind one getdate default. Result of this has 2 lines

```
alter table zamestnanci drop DF__zamestnan__datum__2E1BDC42 go sp_bindefault 'abc' ,'zamestnanci.datum_pridania'
alter table zamestnanci2 drop DF__zamestnan__datum__2F10007B go sp_bindefault 'abc' ,'zamestnanci2.datum_pridania'
```

and i want to execute it in one command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to dynamically generate the SQL **and** execute it in a single set based query.
You'll have to iterate through the results of your select - either in a CURSOR or WHILE loop - and build the generated statement into a variable and then execute that with EXEC or sp_executesql; e.g.

```
    DECLARE @TableName sysname,
        @ConstraintName sysname,
        @ColumnName sysname,
        @sql nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE getdateDefaults CURSOR FAST_FORWARD AS
        SELECT so.name AS TableName,
               sdc.name AS ConstraintName,
               sc.name AS ColumnName
        from sys.objects as so
               join sys.columns as sc on so.object_id=sc.object_id
               join sys.default_constraints as sdc on sc.object_id=sdc.parent_object_id
                                                              and sc.column_id=sdc.parent_column_id
        where so.type='U'
                and so.name like 'z%'
                and sdc.definition='(getdate())';

OPEN getdateDefaults;
FETCH NEXT FROM getdateDefaults INTO @TableName, @ConstraintName, @ColumnName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'alter table '+@TableName+N' drop '+@ConstraintName+N';'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql  @stmt = @sql;
    SET @sql = N' sp_bindefault ''abc'' ,'''+@TableName+'.'+@ColumnName+N''';'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql  @stmt = @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM getdateDefaults INTO @TableName, @ConstraintName, @ColumnName;
END
CLOSE getdateDefaults;
DEALLOCATE getdateDefaults;
```

Comment: this looks good, do i have to write this always or i can make any script? as in shell, that database would remember him and i only call when i need.

Comment: sp_executesql will execute any valid TSQL statement, obviously you will need to alter the cursor content and the dynamic generation but the principal will remain the same

Comment: yes, i think that i understand.. but im asking if i can name this whole your comment for example "bindingscript" and just write exec bindingscript..

Comment: Yes; might be cleaner if you set it up as a stored procedure, that way you could parameterise some of the variable content.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a variable to hold your generated queries, and than execute it:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = (your_query)

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

You should create nvarchar string, so instead of `'alter table '` use `N'alter table '`.

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

It returns more rows and i think u cant store them to parameter

Comment: Ah yes, damn, forgot. You'll have to go with a cursor. See Nick's answer.

Comment: remove "="  from first line (before data type)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (although untested as I don't have your schema)

```
DECLARE @tableName      NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @constraintName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @columnName     NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql            NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @tableName=so.name,
        @constraintName=sdc.name,
        @columnName=sc.name
FROM    sys.objects as so
            JOIN sys.columns as sc
                ON so.object_id=sc.object_id
            JOIN sys.default_constraints as sdc
                ON sc.object_id=sdc.parent_object_id AND sc.column_id=sdc.parent_column_id
WHERE   so.type='U'AND
        so.name LIKE 'z%' AND
        sdc.definition=getdate()

SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @tableName + ' DROP ' + @constraintName + 'go sp_bindefault ''abc'' , ''' +  @columnName + ''
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: `@sql` must be a Unicode variable, that mean `NVARCHAR` data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your string into a cursor e execute both results

```
DECLARE RS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TOP 5 'SELECT * FROM [' + NAME + ']'
    FROM sys.Objects
    WHERE TYPE = 'U'

DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)

OPEN RS
FETCH NEXT FROM RS INTO @TEXT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    FETCH NEXT FROM RS INTO @TEXT

    EXEC (@TEXT)

END

CLOSE RS
DEALLOCATE RS
```